# wxpython: The GridBagSizer made me confused

Tags: python, wxpython

I am new with python GUI and `wxpython` also. Now im facing following problem.

**Here the code is**

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title)

        self.InitUI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def InitUI(self):
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(0, 0)

        text = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Name:")
        sizer.Add(text, pos=(0, 0), flag=wx.ALL, border=5)

        tc = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        sizer.Add(tc, pos=(0, 1), span=(1, 2), flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=5)

        text1 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="address")
        sizer.Add(text1, pos=(1, 0), flag=wx.ALL, border=5)

        tc1 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        sizer.Add(tc1, pos=(1, 1), span=(1, 3), flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=5)

        text11 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="address2")
        sizer.Add(text11, pos=(1, 4), flag=wx.ALL, border=5)

        tc11 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        sizer.Add(tc11, pos=(1, 5), span=(1, 3), flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=5)

        text2 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="age")
        sizer.Add(text2, pos=(2, 0), flag=wx.ALL, border=5)

        tc2 = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        sizer.Add(tc2, pos=(2, 1), flag=wx.ALL, border=5)

        text3 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Mob.No")
        sizer.Add(text3, pos=(2, 2), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, border=5)

        tc3 = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        sizer.Add(tc3, pos=(2, 3), flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=5)

        text4 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Description")
        sizer.Add(text4, pos=(3, 0), flag=wx.ALL, border=5)

        tc4 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        sizer.Add(tc4, pos=(3, 1), span=(1, 3), flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=5)
        sizer.AddGrowableRow(3)

        buttonOk = wx.Button(panel, label="Ok")
        buttonClose = wx.Button(panel, label="Close")

        sizer.Add(buttonOk, pos=(4, 2), flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        sizer.Add(buttonClose, pos=(4, 3), flag=wx.ALL, border=5)

        panel.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)


app = wx.App()
Example(None, title='GridBag Demo')
app.MainLoop()
```

**Here the result is**

[image]

What make me confused is the label `address2`.It does not span three columns obviously.

```
text11 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="address2")
sizer.Add(text11, pos=(1, 4), flag=wx.ALL, border=5)

tc11 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
sizer.Add(tc11, pos=(1, 5), span=(1, 3), flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=5)
```

But the code of `address2` label is same with `address` label except param `pos`.Can someone explain this.

env: python3.7/wxpython4.0.4(newest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the definition of those 3 columns?
Have you defined anything for columns 5,6 and 7 for the `sizer` to work with?
Without something to work with the sizer has no idea how big those columns are, so you must either give it something to work with or define an empty cell size.

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(750,-1))

        self.InitUI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def InitUI(self):
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(0, 7)

        text = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Name:")
        sizer.Add(text, pos=(0, 0), flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
#
# place some dummy text to give the sizer something to work with
#
#        dummy4 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="something")
#        sizer.Add(dummy4, pos=(0, 4), flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
#        dummy5 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="something")
#        sizer.Add(dummy5, pos=(0, 5), flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
#        dummy6 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="something")
#        sizer.Add(dummy6, pos=(0, 6), flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
#        dummy7 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="something")
#        sizer.Add(dummy7, pos=(0, 7), flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
#
# or set a cell size for empty cells
#
        sizer.SetEmptyCellSize((130,20))

        tc = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        sizer.Add(tc, pos=(0, 1), span=(1, 2), flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=5)

        text1 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="address")
        sizer.Add(text1, pos=(1, 0), flag=wx.ALL, border=5)

        tc1 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        sizer.Add(tc1, pos=(1, 1), span=(1, 3), flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=5)

        text11 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="address2")
        sizer.Add(text11, pos=(1, 4), flag=wx.ALL, border=5)

        tc11 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        sizer.Add(tc11, pos=(1, 5), span=(1, 3), flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=5)

        text2 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="age")
        sizer.Add(text2, pos=(2, 0), flag=wx.ALL, border=5)

        tc2 = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        sizer.Add(tc2, pos=(2, 1), flag=wx.ALL, border=5)

        text3 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Mob.No")
        sizer.Add(text3, pos=(2, 2), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, border=5)

        tc3 = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        sizer.Add(tc3, pos=(2, 3), flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=5)

        text4 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Description")
        sizer.Add(text4, pos=(3, 0), flag=wx.ALL, border=5)

        tc4 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        sizer.Add(tc4, pos=(3, 1), span=(1, 3), flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=5)
        sizer.AddGrowableRow(3)

        buttonOk = wx.Button(panel, label="Ok")
        buttonClose = wx.Button(panel, label="Close")

        sizer.Add(buttonOk, pos=(4, 2), flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        sizer.Add(buttonClose, pos=(4, 3), flag=wx.ALL, border=5)

        panel.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)

app = wx.App()
Example(None, title='GridBag Demo')
app.MainLoop()
```

p.s. The layout would probably work better if you simply placed address2 underneath address 1

[image]

Comment: thanks for reply and it was right.this  the empty cell caused that.But i still have two questions.1.is the cell size in GridBagSizer dynamic? 2.can i set default size of the cell(not the empty cell)?

Comment: @放課後 https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.Sizer.html#wx.Sizer and https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.GridBagSizer.html#wx.GridBagSizer -- - The default empty cell size appears to be 10 wide and 20 high